# How to convert binary string value to decimal

Tags: java

How to convert a binary String such as

```
String c = "110010"; // as binary
```

to the value in decimal in Java? (expected result in the example is 50)

Comment: please refrain from posting questions that you have not tried to solve yourself.  [ask]

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Use `Integer.parseInt` (see [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)), that converts your `String` to `int` using base two:

```
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
```

Comment: what if the value of c is too long ?

Answer (score 18):

```
public static int integerfrmbinary(String str){
    double j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        if(str.charAt(i)== '1'){
         j=j+ Math.pow(2,str.length()-1-i);
     }

    }
    return (int) j;
}
```

This piece of code I have written manually. You can also use parseInt as mentioned above .
This function will give decimal value corresponding to the binary string :)

Answer (score 13):

I think you are looking for [Integer.parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).  The second argument takes a radix, which in this case is 2.

```
Integer.parseInt(c, 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int num = Integer.parseInt("binaryString",2);
```

Comment: This solution was provided multiple times, years before this answer was posted.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static Long binToDec(String bin) {
long dec = 0L;
    long pow = 1L;
    for (int i = (bin.length() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = bin.charAt(i);
        dec = dec + (Long.parseLong(c + "") * pow);
        pow = pow * 2;
    }
    return dec;
}
```

or

```
long num = Long.parseLong("101110111",2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have to think about the decimal precision, so you must to limit the bitstring length. Anyway, using BigDecimal is a good choice.

```
public BigDecimal bitStringToBigDecimal(String bitStr){

    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal("0");
    BigDecimal base = new BigDecimal(2);
    BigDecimal temp;
    for(int i=0;i<bitStr.length();i++){
        if(bitStr.charAt(i)== '1'){
            int exponent= bitStr.length()-1-i;
            temp=base.pow(exponent);
            sum=sum.add(temp);
        }

    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: you can test by:str="10000101001001000010111100100110000000000000000000001010111101";

Answer (score 0):

test this, you'll find out that there is a line in the code which contains **Scan.S()** .This is used only for stocking data (String).
So just try this:

PS:Don't forget to save the file as bindec

```
import java.io.*;
class Scan
{        
    public static String S() 
    {
        String x;
    char c;
    boolean erreur;

    do
    {
            x = "";
            erreur = false;

            try
            {
                while((c = (char)System.in.read()) != '\n')
        {
                    if (c != '\r')
                    {
                        x += c;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.print(" > enter String : ");
                erreur = true;
            }
    } while(erreur);

    return x;
    }
public class  bindec{

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int b=0;
        String a;
        System.out.println("bin: ");
        a = Lire.S();
        int j=a.length()-1;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length() ;i++ ){
            if(a.charAt(i)=='1'){
            b += Math.pow(2,j);
        }
        if(a.charAt(i)=='0'){
            b+=0;
        }
        j=j-1;
    }
        System.out.println("dec: "+b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this : [image: 1]
we can write this help function :

```
    public static int convertBinaryToDecimal(String str) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int value = Character.getNumericValue(str.charAt(i));
            result = result * 2 + value;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

let's say `23456789`

it has a binary string of `1011001011110110000010101`

easiest way is to put all copies of the base needed on the left, which should always be `string length - 1` (assuming not leading edge zeros), put and all the coefficients on the right :

```
echo '1011001011110110000010101' |
```

---

```
  mawk 'function __(_) {
      
      print; gsub(/./, "2*(", _)
      return substr(_,   4)
  }
  $!_ = __($_) $!_' FS= OFS=')+' | gtee >( gcat -b | lgp3 >&2; ) | bc
```

---

```
23456789
1011001011110110000010101
```

---

```
 2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(
 +1)+0)+1)+1)+0)+0)+1)+0)+1)+1)+1)+1)+0)+1)+1)+0)+0)+0)+0)+0)+1)+0)+1)+0)+1

 2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(
  1)  )+1)+1)  )  )+1)  )+1)+1)+1)+1)  )+1)+1)  )  )  )  )  )+1)  )+1)  )+1

 2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(
 2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(2*(1)  )+1)+1)))+1))+1)+1)+1)+1)
                                      )+1)+1)  )))  ))+1)  )+1)  )+1
```

> versus the standard form, which is succinct only for base-2,
> and more helpful for polynomials than for bit-string/vector conversion :

```
2^24 + 2^22 + 2^21 + 2^18 + 2^16 + 2^15 + 2^14 + 2^13 + 2^11 + 2^10 + 2^4 + 2^2

1*2^24 + 0*2^23 + 1*2^22 + 1*2^21 + 0*2^20 + 0*2^19 + 
1*2^18 + 0*2^17 + 1*2^16 + 1*2^15 + 1*2^14 + 1*2^13 + 
0*2^12 + 1*2^11 + 1*2^10 + 0*2^ 9 + 0*2^ 8 + 0*2^ 7 + 
0*2^ 6 + 0*2^ 5 + 1*2^ 4 + 0*2^ 3 + 1*2^ 2 + 0*2    + 1
```

---

- Digits are always kept adjacent to one another, in big-endian notation, without the base and exponent getting in the way
- It completely eliminated the power operator `^` from the chain of operations by using nested layers of the base supporting one another instead.
- Count up # of `2*`s (i.e. `(1 << 1)`) to get floor of `log2(x)`

  Similarly, count up # of `10*`s (i.e. `((1 << 3) + (1 << 1)`) in the decimal version to get floor of `log10(x)`
- For each of the `1` bits, the power of 2 exponent associated with it would be just # of closing parenthesis `)` to its right

---

The decimal equivalent of this structure is shown below. If anything, the condensed gapless form of the notation **increases** readability due to close proximity of digits with one another.

```
10*(10*(10*(10*(10*(10*(10*( 
  
  2)+ 3)+ 4)+ 5)+ 6)+ 7)+ 8)+ 9

10*(10*(10*(10*(10*(10*(10*(2)+3)+4)+5)+6)+7)+8)+9
```

But instead of using the minimum of 7 copies of `10` and 8 coefficient digits for a total of **15** numbers, the standard form needs **21** numbers for including superfluous exponents that could be easily derived just by counting layers in nested form.

```
2*10^7 + 3*10^6 + 4*10^5 + 5*10^4 + 
         6*10^3 + 7*10^2 + 8*10   + 9

2*10^7 + 3*10^6 + 4*10^5 + 5*10^4 + 6*10^3 + 7*10^2 + 8*10 + 9
```

The clutter in its gapless form…

```
2*10^7+3*10^6+4*10^5+5*10^4+6*10^3+7*10^2+8*10+9
```

Once you see numbers in any base in this nested form instead of standard notation, then base-conversion becomes a trivial exercise of nothing more than peeling back the nested layers.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void convertStringToDecimal(String binary)
{
    int decimal=0;
    int power=0;
    while(binary.length()>0)
    {
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(binary.charAt((binary.length())-1)+"");
        decimal+=temp*Math.pow(2, power++);
        binary=binary.substring(0,binary.length()-1);
    }
    System.out.println(decimal);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Test it

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BinaryToDecimal{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int binaryNumber = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int number = 0;


    System.out.print("Input binary number: ");
    binaryNumber = input.nextInt();

    //it's going to stop when the binaryNumber/10 is less than 0
    //example:
    //binaryNumber = 11/10. The result value is 1 when you do the next
    //operation 1/10 . The result value is 0     

    while(binaryNumber != 0)
    {
        //Obtaining the remainder of the division and multiplying it 
        //with the number raised to two

        //adding it up with the previous result

        number += ((binaryNumber % 10)) * Math.pow(2,counter);

        binaryNumber /= 10;  //removing one digit from the binary number

        //Increasing counter 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3.....
        counter++;

    }
    System.out.println("Decimal number : " + number);


}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
private static int convertBinaryToDecimal(String strOfBinary){
        int flag = 1, binary=0;
        char binaryOne = '1';
        char[] charArray = strOfBinary.toCharArray();
        for(int i=charArray.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(charArray[i] == binaryOne){
                binary+=flag;
            }
            flag*=2;
        }
        return binary;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    long decimalValue = 0;

    System.out.println("Please enter a positive binary number.(Only 1s and 0s)");

    //This reads the input as a String and splits each symbol into 
    //array list
    String element = scan.nextLine();
    String[] array = element.split("");

    //This assigns the length to integer arrys based on actual number of 
    //symbols entered
    int[] numberSplit = new int[array.length];
    int position = array.length - 1; //set beginning position to the end of array

    //This turns String array into Integer array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        numberSplit[i] = Integer.parseInt(array[i]);
    }
    //This loop goes from last to first position of an array making
    //calculation where power of 2 is the current loop instance number
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (numberSplit[position] == 1) {
            decimalValue = decimalValue + (long) Math.pow(2, i);
        }
        position--;
    }
    System.out.println(decimalValue);
    main(null);

}
```

Comment: just wanted to share my solution :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class BinaryToDecimal
{
  public static void main()
  {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the binary number");
    double s=sc.nextDouble();
    int c=0;
    long s1=0;
    while(s>0)
    {
        s1=s1+(long)(Math.pow(2,c)*(long)(s%10));
        s=(long)s/10;
        c++;
    }
    System.out.println("The respective decimal number is : "+s1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  int base2(String bits) {
    int ans = 0;
    for (int i = bits.length() - 1, f = 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ans += f * (bits.charAt(i) - '0');
      f <<= 1;
    }
    return ans;
  }
```