# Converting binary to base 10 without math.pow( )?

Tags: java, math, base-conversion

I'm looking to create a simple program that will convert binary numbers to decimal numbers, without using `math.pow()`. Here's what I have so far, using `Math.pow` at the end:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class  Question1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a binary number");
    Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String binaryNumber = inputKeyboard.nextLine();
    while (!checkIfBinary(binaryNumber)) {
      System.out.println("That is not a binary number.  Enter a binary number");
      binaryNumber = inputKeyboard.nextLine();
    }
    int decimalNumber = binaryToNumber(binaryNumber);
    System.out.println("Your number in base 10 is " + decimalNumber + ".");
  }

  public static boolean checkIfBinary(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      if(input.charAt(i) != '0' && input.charAt(i) != '1') {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static int binaryToNumber(String numberInput) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberInput.length(); i++) {
      if (numberInput.charAt(i) == '1')  {
        total += (int) Math.pow(2, numberInput.length() - 1 - i);
      }
    }
    return total;
  }
}
```

I'm encountering a problem doing the exponentiation without `math.pow`.  I know I need to use a loop, and this loop should multiply 2 by itself `numberInput.length() - 1 - i` times. But I'm having difficulty implementing this.

Comment: Hint: You can multiply the total by two and add or not add 1 depending on the next digit, which will give you the new total after one more binary digit.

Comment: Uh, you're not converting binary to "decimal".  You're converting binary to the Java internal numeric form -- `int` -- and that just happens to be binary.

Comment: Isn't this line wrong, shouldn't it be " || " instead of &&,  if(input.charAt(i) != '0' && input.charAt(i) != '1')

Comment: You don't need an exponentiation to convert binary number to decimal. I think something like `Integer.parseInt(YourBinaryIntNumber, 2)` does exactly what you need.

Comment: @jdhw, please read my updated answer.

Comment: @SufihanGhori, I appreciate your help but unfortunately in this intro java course, the problem specifies that we only need use "the nextLine method, loops, the length(), charAt(int index)
and equals(String other) methods of Strings" for this question.

Comment: @Johan, when I use || it doesn't recognize any binary number entered.

Comment: Ok but does the checkbinary method work with && ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd work backwards from the end of the string and just calculate the power for each character incrementally:

```
public static int binaryToNumber (String numberInput) {
    int currentPower = 1;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = numberInput.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (numberInput.charAt(i) == '1')  {
            total += currentPower;
        }
        currentPower *= 2;
    }

    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

parse your `String` to integer and provide it the base `2`

```
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(yourStringOfBinary, 2);
```

but keep in mind that the max value of an Integer is `2^31-1` Which in binary is:

```
1111111111111111111111111111111
```

therefore, you will get `java.lang.NumberFormatException` error if you input bigger binary value than above, to solve this issue, use `BigInteger`,

```
int decimalValue = new BigInteger(yourBinaryString, 2).intValue()
```

Answer (score 2):

`Integer` let you do this by specifying the `base` of the entered number :

```
Integer.parseInt("101101101010111", 2);
```

This does not use `Math.pow` :)

This is maybe not what you wanted, but anyway might help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Integer.parseInt.

Similar question has been answered here:

[How to convert binary string value to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal)

Only difference is that in the answer referenced above, they are converting a String ("01101") into a decimal integer.

Also reference the Javadoc [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).