# Need help: Program to convert binary to decimals (Java)

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I would like some help with my code. I'm doing a method to convert binary numbers to decimals. This is my code:

```
public double decimal(double number){
    String num=(number+"");
    char charac;
    double n;
    double cont=0;
    double exp;
    double res=0;
    for(int i=num.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
        charac=num.charAt(i);//obtains digits 1 by 1 and converts to char
        n=(Character)charac;//converts the digit into a number (double)
        exp=Math.pow(2, cont);//makes the exponential function to multiply to n
        n=n*exp;//multiplies exponential with the digit
        res+=n;//adds digit to accumulator
        cont++; 
    }
    return res;
}
```

the problem i'm having is that the numbers get all messed up for whatever reason, like n being assigned 48 in the first loop of the for cycle.
I tried using n as an Int instead and it seemed to be working well but at the second loop of the for cycle it was assigned -2 somehow and that ruined the addition.

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger in Eclipse? Try to step through your code one line at a time to see why n is becoming 48 or -2

Comment: Not an answer but a few remarks:
- this should probably be a `static` method, as it doesn't use `this`;
- `double` looks like both the wrong input type and the wrong result type. Clarifying this would probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
n=(Character)charac;
```

to use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-) otherwise you get the ascii value (not the digit value)

```
n=Character.digit(charac, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains a lot. I was really confused as to where that 48 was coming from

Answer (score 0):

By assigning char to double, it is infact passing on the ASCII value of that digit e.g. 48 is returned for char 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer from [How to convert binary string value to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal) will help you:

```
String c = "110010"; // as binary
    int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(c, 2);
    System.out.println(decimalValue);
```

result: `50`