# I get : cannot invoke length() on the primitive type int

Tags: java, user-interface

We have to make a program that converts Binary numbers into Decimal numbers using a GUI. First I made the program without using a GUI and it was working fine. Then I tried with the GUI and while making the program I keep getting an error message saying "cannot invoke length() on the primitive type int"

```
    int BinaryNumber, DecimalNumber;
            try {
                BinaryNumber = Integer.parseInt(textFieldtUserBinaryInput.getText());

                DecimalNumber = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < BinaryNumber.length(); i++);
                    {
                        Character binary = BinaryNumber.charAt(i);
                        String temp = binary.toString();
                        int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                        DecimalNumber = DecimalNumber * 2 + tempInt;
                        textFieldDecimal.setText(Integer.toString(DecimalNumber));
                    }




            }catch (NumberFormatException exp){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid format for a binary string - Illegal character");
            }
        }
```

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

this is what I had when it was working without trying to do the GUI

```
    public static int ConvertToDecimal(String BinaryNumber)
{
    String pattern = "[0-1]*";
    boolean patternMatched = Pattern.matches(pattern, BinaryNumber);  
    if(patternMatched)
    {
        int Decimal = 0;
        for (int d = 0; d < BinaryNumber.length(); d++)
        {
            Character binary = BinaryNumber.charAt(d);
            String temp = binary.toString();
            int tempInt = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            Decimal = Decimal * 2 + tempInt;
        }
        return Decimal;
    }
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory, and it has nothing to do with a GUI. What's unclear to you?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to have BinaryNumber work in that function. When I did the program normally I had 

        for (int d = 0; d < BinaryNumber.length(); d++)
then when I added the GUI and basically did the same thing it gave me that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot invoke methods on primitive types since they are not objects. In your code you declare `BinaryNumber` and `DecimalNumber` as int, and in the next line `BinaryNumber` is assigned the result from `Integer.parseInt()`. I suggest you declare BinaryNumber and DecimalNumber as `Integer`.

*`Integer` also doesn't seem to have a length() method. Perhaps you're trying to work with a `String`?

** It may be worth taking a look at [How to convert binary string value to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal)

Comment: yes as a string, I'm new at all this and I've spent a lot of time on this and maybe I'm over looking some stuff but this is what I had when it was working fine as a normal program with no GUI

Comment: I just added the code snippet to the original post since I didn't know how to add in correct format as a comment

Comment: Please take a look at the link I added. I'm not sure if your conversion method works properly. Furthermore, if patternMatched is false, it never returns an int.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive types do not have methods because they are not objects in Java.
In your code you are doing BinaryNumber.length() where BinaryNumber is of type int and earlier you used BinaryNumber as String.