# Making a binary to decimal converter

Tags: java, decimal

EDIT: Since there are claims that this is a duplicate question, I will state my stance on why it is not.

1. The other question had posed a problem regarding the conversion of a string input to an integer (the answer deemed correct). This is irrelevant here, as the problem in my case is one of logic.
2. The solutions on the other question cannot correct the problem this question presents (finding the syntactical "charAt" error).
3. Frankly, the context of the other question is beyond the scope of my knowledge in Java.

I have successfully created a program that converts binary numbers to decimal numbers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProblemThree // to convert binary to decimal
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter binary");
    int binary = scan.nextInt();
    int answer = 0;
    int length = String.valueOf(binary).length();
    int[] number = new int[length];
    int[] powerTwo = new int[length];

    // To list every digit separately //
    for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++)
    {
      number[n] = (int) (binary / Math.pow(10, n)) % 10;
    }

    // To set the values in powerTwo to 2 //
    for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++)
    {
      powerTwo[n] = 2;
    }

    // To update the values in powerTwo //
    for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++)
    {
      if (n == 0)
        powerTwo[0] = 1;
      else if (n == 1)
        powerTwo[1] = 2;
      else
        powerTwo[n] *=  powerTwo[n-1];
    }

    // To add if current value is 1 //
    for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++)
    {
      if (number[n] == 1)
        answer += powerTwo[n];
    }
    System.out.println(powerTwo[0]); // for testing
    System.out.println(number[0]); // for testing
    System.out.println("The decimal version of " + binary + " is " + answer + ".");
  }
}
```

Seeing how some of the steps were redundant, I tried to simplify the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ProblemThreeTestFunction
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter binary");
    int binary = scan.nextInt();
    int answer = 0;
    int length = String.valueOf(binary).length();
    String number = String.valueOf(binary);

    for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++)
    {
      if (number.charAt(n) == 1)
        answer += (int)Math.pow(2, n);
    }
    System.out.println("The decimal version of " + binary + " is " + answer + ".");
  }
}
```

I actually have no idea why the simplified code logic does not work. It uses the same concept as my original.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Can you provide an example of incorrect output (and the corresponding input)?

Comment: Sure! Any response inputted in the simplified program gives an output of 0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert binary string value to decimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal)

Comment: You shouldn't be reading the binary into an `int`. It's an incorrect representation as it reads the number as a decimal. E.g. 101 is a hundred and one. This could lead to confusion especially when you try to debug and find that the actual binary value in that number is completely different than 101.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test against the character `'1'`:

```
if (number.charAt(n) == '1')
```

not the number 1 that you are currently doing:

```
if (number.charAt(n) == 1) // WRONG!
```

Also, since `charAt` counts from the left, and binary expansion counts from the right, you need to reverse the sense. Change

```
Math.pow(2, n)
```

to

```
Math.pow(2, length - 1 - n)
```

Comment: Was about to say that, but even with that, it won't work properly. He is first of all doing this `String number = String.valueOf(binary);` with his binary number, so if entering `0010` it will become `10` from parsing it. I think his logic is wrong there.

Comment: I slapped myself when I read the comment thinking I was dumb, but I still have the logic error.

Comment: @OlarAndrei - His logic is inefficient, but not wrong. The leading zeroes disappear, but that won't change the resulting value. (Binary `0010` and binary `10` both end up as decimal `2`.)

Comment: This time, every input I enter outputs a "1."

Comment: Interesting development: I tested an input of 11; it outputted 3.

Comment: @GosuDa - Ooh. One other problem, `charAt` measures from the left, so you need to raise 2 to the power `length - 1 - n` instead of `n`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp That is what I was talking about.

Comment: @OlarAndrei - Ah. That really has nothing to do with losing leading digits; it has to do with powers of 2 and `charAt` counting from different origins.

Comment: OH! Basically, I needed to go from right to left. Could I have done that by reversing the for loop? I also thought that that could be the issue, but I tried to change the for loop to (int n = length - 1; n >= 0; n--), and the same issue occurred.

Comment: @GosuDa - No, reversing the loop doesn't fix anything. The problem is for each value of `n` individually, not the order in which it takes on different values.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use:

```
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
```

But if you use this you Need to use `scan.nextLine()` not `scan.nextInt()`.

This will just convert your binary number to decimal using base 10 like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal).

Comment: That wouldn't really help?
Doesn't that just convert string to int?

Comment: That is not the problem. I do not need to convert integer to string. Sure, my code is a little inefficient, but the logic problem still remains.

Comment: @WasteD your answer was good. Now is bad. the number says in which system is the input. Numbers are stored in memory in binary anyway. We just got used to displaying them in decimal system but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing with digit 1, it should be character 1 i.e. '1'.

```
for (int n = 0; n <= length - 1; n++) {
  if (number.charAt(n) == '1') {
    answer += (int)Math.pow(2, length - n - 1);
  }
}
```

Also you need to correct the exponent part.