# Java converting binary string to decimal

Tags: java, binary, decimal, converters

I tried to write a code that convert binary to decimal. But it gives me a huge result. Can you please tell me how to do it. I saw codes using remainder and give correct results but I really wonder what is the fault there in my code, thanks

```
    double number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        double temp = str.charAt(16-1 - i) * Math.pow(2, i);
        number = number + temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is where your code went wrong:

```
str.charAt(16-1 - i) * Math.pow(2, i);
```

You just multiplied a `char` by a `double`. This will evaluate to the ASCII value of `char` times the double, not 0 or 1.

You need to convert this to an integer first:

```
Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(str.charAt(16-1 - i))) * Math.pow(2, i)
```

Or, you can just:

```
Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `str.charAt(16-1-i)`, you get back a char, which represents a single letter. So you don't get the number 0 or 1, but the corresponding letters. As letters are represented as integers in Java, you don't get a type error. The number to represent a 0 letter is 48, for 1 it's 49. To convert your letter into the correct number, you have to write `(str.charAt(16-1-i)-48)` instead of `str.charAt(16-1-i)`.

Answer (score 0):

People here have already answered what went wrong. Doing `Math.pow(2, i)` on a character produced inconsistent result.

If you are going to convert binary value to an `Integer` this could help you.

```
Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2)
```

Where the value `2` is the `radix` value.

[Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) and similar SO Discussion on the same topic is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal).