# Making a class that processes binary numbers and converts to decimal value, which client class prints out

Tags: java, string, parsing, binary, hex

I have a HexStringHandlerClient class that looks like this:

```
package experiment7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HexStringHandlerClient
{
  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print( "Enter a hexadecimal number > " );
    String hex = scan.next( );

    HexStringHandler hsh = new HexStringHandler( );
    hsh.parse( hex );

    if ( hsh.isValid( ) )
      System.out.println( hex + " = " + hsh.getNumber( ) );
    else
      System.out.println( hex + " is not a valid hex number." );
  }
}
```

I also have the HexStringHandler class, which looks like this:

```
package experiment7;
public class HexStringHandler 
                implements StringHandler, Validator
{
  private boolean validHex;
  private int number;

  /** default constructor
  *  initializes number to 0
  *  and validHex to true
  */
  public HexStringHandler( )
  {
    validHex = true;
    number = 0;
  }

  /** processLetter method
  * @param c  the character to process
  * if c is between 10 and 15 (hex A through F),
  * uses its value to update the decimal number
  * otherwise, character is invalid letter
  */
  @Override
  public void processLetter( char c )
  { 
    int n = Character.getNumericValue( c );
    if ( n >= 10 && n <= 15 ) // valid hex character?
      number = 16 * number + n; // update number
    else // invalid hex character
      validHex = false;
  }

  /** processDigit method
  * @param c  the character to process
  * uses numeric value to update the decimal value
  */
  @Override
  public void processDigit( char c )
  { 
    int n = Character.getNumericValue( c );
    number = 16 * number + n; // update number
  }

  /** processOther method
  * @param c  the character to process
  * character is not a valid hex digit
  */
  @Override
  public void processOther( char c )
  { 
    // c is an invalid hex character
    validHex = false;
  }

  /** isValid method
  * @return true if all characters
  * in String are valid hex characters,
  * else returns false
  */
  public boolean isValid( )
  {
    return validHex;
  }

  /** getNumber method
  * @return if valid, returns the calculated decimal value
  * else, returns -1
  */
  public int getNumber( )
  {
    if ( isValid( ) )
      return number;
    else
      return -1;
  }
}
```

Finally, I have another client class for a BinStringHandler class:

```
package lab7;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinStringHandlerClient
{
  public static void main( String [] args )
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print( "Enter a binary number > " );
    String bin = scan.next( );

    BinStringHandler bsh = new BinStringHandler( );
    bsh.parse( bin );

    if ( bsh.isValidBin( ) )
      System.out.println( bin + " = " + bsh.getBinNumber( ) );
    else
      System.out.println( bin + " is not a valid binary number." );
  }
}
```

My question is, how would I make the BinStringHandler class, which would process binary numbers (rather than hexadecimal like the HexStringHandler class) and convert them to decimal values, which its client class would print out? The class should look similar to my HexStringHandler class, but I am a bit lost on how to adjust it to do this, specifically in the processLetter and processDigit methods. This is what I have so far:

```
package experiment7;

public class BinStringHandler 
        implements StringHandler, Validator
{
  private boolean validBin;
  private int binNumber;

  public BinStringHandler( )
  {
    validBin = true;
    binNumber = 0;
  }

@Override
public boolean isValid() {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void processLetter(char c) {
    //Insert code here
}
@Override
public void processDigit(char c) {
    //Insert code here
}
@Override
public void processOther(char c) {
    validBin = false;

}

public boolean isValidBin() {
    return validBin;
}
public int getBinNumber() {
    if ( isValidBin( ) )
        return binNumber;
    else
        return -1;
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert binary string value to decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437987/how-to-convert-binary-string-value-to-decimal)

Comment: You should do the same thing for binary as you did for hexadecimal. Just use 2 instead of 16.

Comment: By the way, you are not actually converting to a decimal value (and that's not what is required). You are converting to an int. An int is not a decimal value. It just appears to be decimal when you print it. The concept of "decimal" is something that makes sense only when you refer to a String, and an int is not a String.